# Ruby on Rails with large db: Keep attributes in one table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder what is best practice for Ruby on Rails (with MySQL) with large databases: 
If I have a database with millions of "persons" and attributes that are often used (like "name") and others that are used only on special occasions (like "phone number") should they all be kept on one table "persons" or should the latter be put into an additional table like "persons_additional_attributes"?

I think two tables would be better in terms of performance but I could not find any text addressing this topic.

Comment: Having a single table should be fine from the DB perspective, the but issue lies with Rails' ActiveRecord: When you do a `Person.find(1)`, it will trigger a `SELECT *` statement, even though you may only need the values for columns `id`, `name` but not `phone_number`, etc. There are options here: fix this flaw by changing the DB structure (2+ tables, one with common attributes, others having not-so-used attrs), OR make the change in your app: when you know you will only need `name` and `id`, perform a reduced select such as `Person.select(:id, :name).find(1)`.

Comment: So there is no "Rails way", the problem does not officially exist? I'm completely unsure which way I would prefer, especially since I don't know which requests or sorts might be necessary in a later phase. 2 tables seem to be better to maintain, unlesss sorting or finding people by phone number will be needed some day.

Comment: This seems like a [database normalization](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+normalization) question. Which has nothing to do (directly) with Rails, really. I would hazard to say that there is no one-size-fits-all answer to how one should structure one's database. It is entirely context-specific.

Comment: Also, don't do premature optimization yet. If you are not 100% sure that your web app will require this feature in the next months, then don't spend too much time on this non-issue. To address your questions about the real usage of your web app, there are tons of monitoring tools (+ you can create your own) to get stats about these fields are used, etc. You can find posts about how to deal with Rails "scalability issues" as well to help in your decision making.

Comment: I would think the attribute 'name' should live on the person model. AFAIK, you want to extract columns to another model if the string itself will be repeated over and over. Like if the person has a title or role, you could extract that to a separate table

Comment: So, from database normalization and general database point of view it's rather "all attributes in one table". When I get perfomance issues, it is not because the db is wrong but because Rails uses `SELECT *` and I'd rather optimize Rails than change the db. I think this will be my way of proceeding.